# PHP can't get content of a file from a remote path with no error returned

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I read some files from a remote path, I can access that file from Windows Explorer with 0 errors.

I use XAMPP and my php code for test is the following:

```
$file = file_get_contents('\\remote\file.xml');
echo $file;
// or
$file2 = fopen('\\remote\file.xml', "r");
echo $file2;
```

The problem is that I can't get the content from the file but both functions don't return an error code or something.
Thanks!

Comment: if you pass a remote path to `file_get_contents` or `fopen`, you need to specify it as a URL. What exactly are you passing in?

Comment: You "can acces that file from windows explorer with 0 errors" - so is it a REMOTE file (not on your computer), or is it a LOCAL file (on your computer)?

Comment: @VladutZzZ share the path of your remote file

Comment: @light if you didn't know, you can acces a remote file with windows explorer, just copy+paste to addres bar and it's working. You can try.

Comment: @anujnehra \\rmcontroller\Logs\\*files*.log

Comment: @VladutZzZ i know you can access a remote file using Windows Explorer. I'm asking: is it a valid URL? The path in your question `\\remote\file.xml` is not a valid URL

Comment: why it's not valid ? i just changed some names, but it's like that, and it's look correctly.

Comment: @VladutZzZ `\\rmcontroller\Logs*files*.log` is not a valid URL. If you don't believe me, copy and paste it into your web browser now :D

Comment: My friend it's NOT a link for a browser.

Comment: who said it's a URL link ?

Comment: I think you don't understand what is a URL. This will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax

Comment: My friend what do you don't understand \\rmcontroller = server ip i can use 172.21.3.92 , Logs it's folder, and in Logs i have the files. What is the problem with \\rmcontroller\Logs\file.log ?

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` will return only the content or false or failure, to see possible errors do `var_dump($http_response_header);` right after calling the `file_get_contents` function

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php